# ngmap does not generate markers on document ready

Tags: angularjs, document-ready

I'm using ngmap with ui-router and the only way I can generate markers is with setTimeout or interval/timeout. There are many posts showing how to run function in angular controller on document ready but none of them works for me.

```
setTimeout($scope.GenerateMapMarkers,500);
        /*angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            $scope.GenerateMapMarkers;
        })*/
```

Maybe because I am running that 'GenerateMapMarkers' inside 'monitorCtrl' and map is in 'partials/partial-monitor.html'. For some reason ngmap examples are always using  setTimeout, interval or timeout

```
.state('monitor', {
                url: '/monitor',
                controller: 'monitorCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'partials/partial-monitor.html',
                authenticate: false
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
angular.element(document).ready(function ()
{
    //Code for generate marker  
});
```

Change your ng-map.min.js file to..

```
<script src="//rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Getting 'TypeError: $scope.load is not a function'

Comment: Its just my function where i have write code as per my requirement. you have to write code for marker generate

Comment: that is part of my initial question , I tried to run $scope.GenerateMapMarkers on document ready (inside brackets) , nothing happens , only map displays

Comment: create plunker for that

Comment: in fact there is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZATMU5hsSNLNUp37wPj?p=preview , I am trying to get rid of interval

Comment: your map script is 404.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92620/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-irom).